# Storing Secret token information at runtime from ADF to Key Vault dynamically

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I have a scenario for using Azure Key vault.

1. I have stored a refresh token in Key Vault. Retrieved the token from key vault in ADF using the web activity. Call the service provider endpoint to generate the Access Token based on refresh token.
2. I want to store above generated Access token from ADF to Key Vault. How Can i do that?

I went through many articles but did not find any solution on storing the information generated in ADF to Key Vault.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make Rest API call from Azure Data Factory using web activity to store secret in to Azure Key Vault.

Here is the link for Rest API reference:

Sets a secret in a specified key vault.
The SET operation adds a secret to the Azure Key Vault. If the named secret already exists, Azure Key Vault creates a new version of that secret. This operation requires the secrets/set permission.

Set Secret - [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/set-secret) (Azure Key Vault)
Learn more about [Key Vault Set Secret Operations].

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me.

Comment: Sounds Great! Could you please accept it as an answer so the question stands as answered for the other community members.